# Add different TextViews to ScrollView

Tags: android, textview, scrollview

I Have activity that get some data from the internet, and shows it to the screen.
I'm using scroll view cause it's long text, I also want different text style for a different data,so I use few textViews with a different style and to show it on the Activity screen,
my problem is that scroll view can handle only one view, so how can I use scrolling to show different style of Text view, I tried to add LinearLayout to the scrollView and add all the textViews dynamically in code to this LinearLayout ,but I'm getting exception - scroll view can host only one direct child.

The code below:

```
/** this is the function, which called from the onClick method.
wanted data object contains 2 strings title message and the message itself.

When debug the code i can see that there's two String values in each loop.
but i cant add the linearLayout to my scrollView - exception ScrollView can host only one direct child */

    private void showResult(ArrayList<WantedData> result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView title;
        TextView data;
        scrollLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LlScrollView);  
        for (WantedData curr : result) {
            if (curr.getTitle() == null) {
                break;
            }

            title = new TextView(this);
            title.setText(curr.getTitle());

            scrollLayout.addView(title, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            data = new TextView(this);
            data.setText(curr.getData());   
            scrollLayout.addView(data, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        }
        scroll.addView(scrollLayout, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        //at the onCreate method -  scroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.SvShowTextFromServer);
    }
```

the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/layout_reffernce"
        layout="@layout/explore" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Enter City" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/EtCity"
                android:layout_width="210dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.14"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bSearchCity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Search" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Enter State" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EtState"
            android:layout_width="253dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/SvShowTextFromServer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LlScrollView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/backround"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Provide code of adding `TextView` please

Comment: scrollLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
  
  scroll.addView(scrollLayout, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
     LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  for (WantedData curr : result) {
   if (curr.getTitle() == null) {
    break;
   }

   title = new TextView(this);
   title.setText(curr.getTitle());

   scrollLayout.addView(title, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
     LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   data = new TextView(this);
   data.setText(curr.getData()); 
   scrollLayout.addView(data, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
     LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have defined a `LinearLayout` in XML you don't have to create a new `LinearLayout` in your code but you have to retrieve the existing one in this way

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LlScrollView);
```

Otherwise you have to remove the `LinearLayout` in your XML and add all by code.

Comment: Thank's I know , but it's not the problem im afraid, i've deleted the creation at the code and still get exception scroll view can host only one direct child.. maybe each text view added to the LinearLayout is like added to the scroll view

Comment: @david: it's very strange, report all the code of `onCreate()` method - editing your question -

Answer (score 1):

The problem is double creating of container in `ScrollView`. You should not create it in activity, but take already defined from xml:

```
LinearLayout scrollContainer = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LlScrollView);
for (...) {
    //create here some text
    scrollLayout.addView(text);
}
```

Comment: Thank's I know , but it's not the problem Im afraid, I've deleted the creation at the code and added reference to the xml file ,still get exception, scroll view can host only one direct child.. maybe each text view added to the LinearLayout is like added to the scroll view